# Adhoc app not showing in iTunes when dragged in

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, provisioning, adhoc

Distribution certificate recently expired so had to create another one. Everything seemed to work ok - I made a zipped build with the profile & app file. Sent to a co-worker who installed with no problem.

Sent to another who had a "signer invalid" message and the client I sent to says they get a "do you want to replace embedded mobile provisioning profile?" message, which I prompt them to say yes too, and then the app does not appear on their list.

So iTunes accepts the app but nothing shows. Confused as to how it can have different results on different machines.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did they sync with iTunes afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Don/iWasRobbed, they did have expiring provisioning profiles which they deleted, and they did attempt a sync afterwards. The app still wouldn't appear when dragged into iTunes so I had them come into the office, when connecting their iPhone to my computer Xcode indicated their OS version 4.01 was not supported by my current SDK(s) (only up to 4.0!).

Downloaded Xcode 3.2.3 again with SDK 4.01 and their iPhone status light switched from a yellow to green light and built.

Comment: Good to know you got it solved.  You should accept your own answer since you figured out what caused it.

Comment: Cheers. (oops - I answered and thought it would auto-accept!)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing appears in iTunes or on the phone?  On the phone, if you go to Settings > General > Profiles, you can delete the expired provisioning profile.  On a Mac, go to ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles and delete it from there.  On Windows XP, it will be in C:/Documents and Settings/username/Application Data/Apple Computer/MobileDevice/ and on  Vista and 7, C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Apple Computer/MobileDevice/.

Once the expired profile is deleted, iTunes may behave better.  Also note that (I think it was 3.1.3) a version of iOS had a bug that would refuse to run any provisioned app if one profile was invalid.